# Vuejs SearchBar ||using filter method not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-filter

I quite new to Vue js I am trying to use the computed method to create a search bar to only search through the name but I'm getting "this.info.filter" is not a function

```js
<template>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search by name">
   <div class="content" v-for="student in filterName " v-bind:key="student.id">
      <img class="image" :src="student.pic" alt="">
      <div class="student-info">
          <h1 class="info">{{student.firstName +" "+ student.lastName}}</h1>
          <div class="infomation">
            <p class="cop">{{ student.company }}</p>
            <p class="ski">{{ student.skill }}</p>
            <p class="email">{{ student.email }}</p>
            <p class="grade">{{ student.grades }}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Student.vue",
  data() {
    return {
      students: '',
      search: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
        .get('https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students')
        .then((res) => {
          this.students = (res.data.students)
        })
  },
  computed :{
    filterName:function (){
      return this.info.filter((student)=>{
        return student.company.matcth(this.search);
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

First time using StackOverflow too please ignore the errors

Comment: it should be `match` not `matcth`

Comment: Inside the function `filterName` the keyword `this` refers to that very function, which has no property `info`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a declaration/initialization for `this.info` anywhere in your code.

The reason you're getting that error is because filter is trying to run on an undefined variable (`this.info` is `undefined`).

You might want to initialize that to an empty array within `data`.